# BFS on weighted undirected G

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to perform BFS on a weighted undirected graph. can anyone give me an algorithm for converting weighted graph to unweighted so that I can use it as input for BFS algorithm. thanks.

Comment: What do the weights mean?  Why do you want to convert the graph back to an unweighted graph?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Probably he wants to find the shortest path (since BFS on unweighted graph will give the shortest path).

Answer (score 0):

To perform transformation of weighted undirected graph in one unweighted he algorithm is very simple. Is summarized to change of nonzero elements in adjacency matrix to true and zero elements into false. However, you can apply BFS into weighted undirected graph as well.